Mapping multiple db context issue with Entity Framework
I'm currently using ABP Framework and have two different DbContexts because I have two different modules.
In my second module, I have a state entity like this:
[ReplaceDbContext(typeof(IIdentityProDbContext))]
[ReplaceDbContext(typeof(ISaasDbContext))]
[ConnectionStringName("Default")]
public class CommonDbContext : AbpDbContext<CommonDbContext>, ICommonDbContext, IIdentityProDbContext, ISaasDbContext
{
    public DbSet<State> States { get; set; }

    public CommonDbContext(DbContextOptions<CommonDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        builder.ConfigureIdentityPro();
        builder.ConfigureSaas();
        builder.ConfigureCommon();
    }

    // ConfigureCommon class
    builder.Entity<State>(b =>
    {
        b.ToTable(CommonConstants.DbTablePrefix + "State", CommonConstants.DbSchema);
        b.ConfigureByConvention();
        b.Property(x => x.Name).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(256);
        b.Property(x => x.Abbreviation).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(256);
    });
}

Now, I want to use it in my first module, so I did it like this:
[ReplaceDbContext(typeof(IIdentityProDbContext))]
[ReplaceDbContext(typeof(ISaasDbContext))]
[ReplaceDbContext(typeof(ICommonDbContext))]

[ConnectionStringName("Default")]
public class MyPrimaryDbContext :  AbpDbContext<MyPrimaryDbContext>, IIdentityProDbContext,
    ISaasDbContext, IMyPrimaryDbContext, ICommonDbContext
{
    public DbSet<State> States { get; set; }

    public MyPrimaryDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyPrimaryDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        builder.ConfigureIdentityPro();
        builder.ConfigureSaas();
    }
}

Now, when I try to get the states from the AppService inside the main module as:
 var stateQuery = await _stateRepository.GetQueryableAsync();

It throws an error:

Invalid object name 'States'

Did I miss something, or why is it not mapped correctly?

It will depend on what the state repository is trying to do with which DbContext. It would appear the repo isn't referencing the DbContext you expect, or there is an inner exception. If you have explicit configuration for the entity as you seem to:  builder.Entity<State>(...) then this configuration will be needed in the alternate DbContext as well. Entity declarations can be shared between different bounded DbContexts, I do recommend using the IEntityTypeConfiguration<T> implementations when sharing entity definitions to avoid the duplicate declarations, but it works either way.

Ohh, I see, it got solved using builder.ConfigureCommon(); on the onModelCreating override, thanks @StevePy
